# Repeat string in one element in a set using Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was making the difference between two sets to see what had changed when I noticed that whenever I had one element which was a repeated sequence it would be represented as only one char.

Example:

```
>>> set("aaaa") 
{'a'}
```

How can I represent it as {'aaaa'} so I can make the diff between two sets and get the right value? If it's not possible using sets, what is the easiest way to compare two data structures and get the diff in python3?

Example:

```
 >>> a = set(['red', 'blue', 'green'])
 >>> b = set(['red', 'green'])
 >>> a
 {'green', 'red', 'blue'}
 >>> b
 {'red', 'green'}
 >>> a - b
 {'blue'}
```

Comment: Your 2nd example works just like you want it. Could you describe more clearly what is wrong?

Comment: I was checking with set('aaa') and not set(['aaa']). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't call `set` on a single `str` unless you want to treat the `str` as a sequence of individual characters to be uniquified (that is, `set('aaaa')` is equivalent to `set(['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'])`, because Python `str` are iterables of their own characters). If you want a `set` containing only `"aaaa"`, you do either `{'aaaa'}` (set literal syntax) or `set(['aaaa'])` (set constructor wrapping a one-element sequence containing the `str`). The former is more efficient when you have a fixed number of items to put in a set, the latter works with existing iterables (e.g. `set(mysequence)`).

In Python 3.5+, you can [use literal syntax more flexibly](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/), creating sets from a combination of single values and iterables, e.g. `{'aaaa', *mysequence}` where `mysequence` is `[1, 2, 3]` would be equivalent to typing `{'aaaa', 1, 2, 3}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to set a variable to `{'aaaa'}` like in your example, simply change the `set` assignment from `set("aaaa")` to `set(['aaaa'])`.